# fast powering method with recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I'm writing an instance method to compute power of natural numbers. I'm using the fast powering method something like base^ power = (base^power/2)^power/2 if power is even, otherwise base^power =  base*(base^power/2)^power/2. My code below causes overflow error.

here is my code:

```
 @Override
public void power(int p) {
    assert p >= 0 : "Violation of: p >= 0";

    // TODO - fill in body
    NaturalNumber one = new NaturalNumber1L(1);
    if (p == 0) {
        this.copyFrom(one);
    } else if (p > 1) {
        this.power(p);
    }

    if (p > 1) {
        if (p % 2 == 0) {
            this.power(p / 2);
            this.multiply(this);
        } else {
            this.multiply(this);
            this.power((p - 1) / 2);
            this.multiply(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this code:

```
else if (p > 1) {
    this.power(p);
}
```

Here if the `p` is bigger than 1 you are recursively calling the function without doing any modification to `p`. At the following execution the same if will be entered and the function called again. This repeats until overflow.